# mysql find closest list of numbers in multi column

Tags: mysql, sql

here is the table and values

```
ID  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
______________________

1   60  11  29  50  90
2   59  12  32  51  81
3   61  16  30  53  92
4   66  13  34  55  91
5   57  14  28  49  73
```

and this is the list of numbers [59,13,33,56,94]  (I mean 59 for c1 , 13 for c2 and ..)

now how to select top 3 closest record base on list

Comment: Please define "top 3 closest record base on list".

Comment: Revise your schema. E.g (group_id,c,score)

Comment: What's the metric for the distance?

Comment: look this is just a compare between two list of numbers , if we have only one col (c1) the query should be -> select * from c1 where c1 >= 59 limit 2 ; select * from c1 where c1 < 59 limit 2 but in this situation we have multi cols and a list of numbers

Comment: I forgot order by c1 asc and order by c1 desc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you may mean closest by something like Euclidean distance.

The idea is `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by pow(c1 - 59, 2) + pow(c2 - 13, 2) + pow(c3 - 33, 2) +
         pow(c4 - 56, 2) + pow(c5 - 94, 2)
limit 3;
```

Comment: Or is it plain distance? The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT *, ABS(c1-a1) + ABS(c2-a2) + ABS(c3-a3) + ABS(c4 - a4) + ABS(c5-a5) AS total
FROM tab
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 59 a1,13 a2,33 a3,56 a4,94 a5) l
ORDER BY total LIMIT 3
```

Comment: That would be "average". What about "min squares"? The question is not clear enough.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, the metric for distance should be more specific.